# Why open() in python not use windows enviroment variables like a import

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a file on my desktop, with the full path:

> C:\Users\Evgeny\Desktop\f.py

but python was ran from:

> C:\Users\Evgeny

The problem is, that I can't do `exec(open('f.py').read())`

I include the first path to enviroment variables, but it doesn't work.
For example, when I do

`import f` it works completely okay.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dgtlm.png)

Can it be possible to run the open('f.py') from another directory  not using full path to the file?

Comment: Because `open()` is not a tool to find executables or loadable code. If you used `cat f.py` in the shell, it would not find the file either.

Comment: You'll have to replicate the search work Python does; look at the [`importlib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html). Python does a *lot* of work under the hood to find the right module.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your fast reply! Now I understand how `open()` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`open()` is a tool to open *any file on the filesystem*. It is not a tool to find Python modules.

Python's import machinery is fairly complex (it can be extended, adjusting how modules are found or loaded) and out of the box supports cached bytecode files with different extensions (`.pyc`, `.pyd`, in a `__bytecache__` directory or not), loading from `.zip` files, and loading native extensions, all from a series of configurable directories listed on `sys.path`. This machinery is also there to allow you to override modules with different versions, simply by putting them in a different location on the search path.

The vast majority of use-cases for the `open()` function, however, do not need this machinery, you want to open your cat pictures from your Desktop, and not have to worry about the `cat.py` module in a different directory.

You can re-use the module resolution behaviour of the import machinery by using [the `importlib.util.find_spec()` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.find_spec):

```
from importlib.util import find_spec

module_spec = find_spec('f')
if module_spec is not None:
    with open(module_spec.origin) as module_source:
        exec(module_source.read())
```

This does require that your `Desktop` folder is on your `sys.path` module search path.